# Access 2007 and storing decimal value

Tags: c#, ms-access, decimal

I can see alot of topics already, but none solved my problem.

I'm from Slovenia.
I'm using English version of Access 2007.
Using c#.

My locale settings are all set to Slovenian.

I have a access database with decimal column.
When I try to save `5,4` into it, it ignores , and stores `54`. If i try to store `5.4` into it, it also ignores . and stores `54`.

I'm using datatables to manipulate data in code.

```
public static DataSet DbData;
public static DataRow DbRow;
```

I have tried following solutions, none of them work (always using `5,4` for input):

```
DbRow[6] = Convert.ToDecimal(txtNovCena.Text); // value of DbRow[6] is 5,4
DbRow[6] = Decimal.Parse(txtNovCena.Text, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("NL-nl").NumberFormat); // value of DbRow[6] is 5,4
DbRow[6] = Decimal.Parse(txtNovCena.Text, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("EN-us").NumberFormat); // value of DbRow[6] is 54
DbRow[6] = Decimal.Parse(txtNovCena.Text, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sl-SI").NumberFormat); // value of DbRow[6] is 5,4

DbRow[6] = txtNovCena.Text.Replace(",", "."); // value of DbRow[6] is 54
```

What is stored in DB after

```
DbAdapter.Update(DbData);
```

is always `54`.

What else can I try?

EDIT:
Also, if I try to run this sql statement directly in Access:

```
UPDATE Sifrant
SET cena = 1,1
WHERE ID = 2;
```

I get Syntax error in statement

But it works with:

```
UPDATE Sifrant
SET cena = 1.1
WHERE ID = 2;
```

Decimal separator is visible as , in GUI of opened accdb file.

Comment: For now only option viable is turning decimal column into text column and then parsing from string to decimal in code. But i would like to avoid this..

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it has anything to do with your locale. "SET cena = 1,1..." will never work in Access (**VBA**) no matter which locale you are in. Unless, I am missing something.

Try using *OleDb* classes. I think this (very generic) solution should work:

```
private void UpdateRecord(string connectionString)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE Sifrant SET cena = 1.1 WHERE ID = 2", connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

It may not be exactly what you are looking for, but should provide you an idea of alternative solutions.

Comment: Yes, that would be a solution, but i have alot of stuff to put into the DB at the same time, and writing SQL statements is a bit dull for me..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Decimal` fields have a number of issues in Access and it's generally recommended [not to use them](http://allenbrowne.com/bug-08.html).
It seems like there is an underlying bug somewhere in how OleDB talks to the driver.

After some testing I could replicate your problem.
Here are a couple of solutions:

1. Are you sure you need a Decimal field in your database?
   Seems silly, but are you 100% sure that the range of values you need to store in the database really warrant a `Decimal` and not a simple `Double` instead?
   Just change the numeric type of your database field in Access if you don;t *really* need a Decimal type.
2. Use `OleDbType.Double` or `OleDbType.Currency`
   When defining the `OldDbParameter` for that field, use `OledDbType.Double` or `OledDbType.Currency` instead of `OledDbType.Decimal`.
   Be careful though that the value saved may be rounded, so test thoroughly if you require precision beyond what .Net offers for these types .

**Additonal tests:**

- I also tried to change the culture of the executing thread to en-US or use the Invariant culture, but it doesn't work, the issue does appear to be a specific mismatch between how .Net talks to the Jet/Ace database engine for its updates.
- I tried using Odbc instead of OleDb, but I got an error `ERROR [07006] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Restricted data type attribute violation` when using `OdbcType.Decimal`.

**Test code:**

I created an Access `Database1.accdb` with a table `myTest` that has 3 fields:

- `ID`, an Autonumber
- `ValueDecimal`, defined as a Decimal with a Precision of 6
- `ValueDouble`, defined as a Double

I switched my Windows regional settings to Slovenian before running the tests:

```
static void tryoledb() {
    var strAccessConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Database1.accdb";
    string strAccessSelect = "SELECT * FROM myTest";

    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
    OleDbConnection myAccessConn = null;
    myAccessConn = new OleDbConnection(strAccessConn);
    OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, myAccessConn);
    OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

    myAccessConn.Open();
    myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "myTest");

    var mytable = myDataSet.Tables["myTest"];
    DataRowCollection dra = mytable.Rows;

    // Set the field ValueDecimal 
    dra[0][1] = 5.4;
    dra[1][1] = 5.4m;
    dra[2][1] = decimal.Parse("5.4");
    dra[3][1] = decimal.Parse("5,4");

    // Set the field ValueDouble 
    dra[0][2] = 5.4;
    dra[1][2] = 5.4m;
    dra[2][2] = double.Parse("5.4");
    dra[3][2] = double.Parse("5,4");

    var command = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE myTest SET ValueDecimal = ?, ValueDouble = ? WHERE ID = ?", myAccessConn);
    var p = command.Parameters.Add("ValueDecimal", OleDbType.Decimal); // Change to OldDbType.Double to make it work
    p.SourceColumn = "ValueDecimal";
    p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;

    p = command.Parameters.Add("ValueDouble", OleDbType.Double);
    p.SourceColumn = "ValueDouble";
    p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;

    p = command.Parameters.Add("ID", OleDbType.Integer);
    p.SourceColumn = "ID";
    p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;

    myDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = command;
    myDataAdapter.Update(mytable);
    myAccessConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Will try to use double tommorow, will report progress:D