# Currency format on a try parse

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing

I'm trying to do a tryparse on a single with the proper culture setted and allowing the currency symbol but nothing seems to work

This is the condition

```
If (Not Single.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString, NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, dTemp) OrElse dTemp < 0) Then
                    MsgBox("La valeur ne doit pas être négative ni être une lettre. Ne laisser pas la case vide non plus.")
                    e.Cancel = True
                End If
```

With a value like `98,00 $` it go into the condition....

So how do I make it understand that the Currency is not to be taken care of, without some complciated string builder, basicly what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the parameter for NumberStyles to `NumberStyles.Currency`

```
If (Not Single.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString, NumberStyles.Currency, _
                        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, dTemp) OrElse dTemp < 0) Then
  .....
```

However if you expect your string to be a currency value, probably I would use a decimal instead of a single

Comment: I would to but the database seems to not like it when I update it, even if the column are set to decimal refer to this, I still got  no answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082763/oledbexception-entering-decimal-into-decimal-not-working if you want to give a shot ^^''

Comment: This post seems to be your answer for the decimal problem with MS Access, I feel your pain....:-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787003/access-2007-and-storing-decimal-value

Comment: Thank, finally someone who understand how MS access can be a pain in the ass, but hey it's a school homework and he want a MS access DB x)